# Solving a Thevenin equivalent circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

Suppose \$R_{1}\$ and \$R_{2}\$ are replaced by resistors of unknown values which are different from those assumed in part (a).

Using a variable external voltage source, a student applies \$+1.5V\$ between terminals a and b (a is positive relative to b) and measures a current \$i_{0}\$ of \$-0.1A\$. When the external voltage is \$+3V\$, the external voltage source  generates power and \$i_{0}\$ is \$+0.2A\$.

Recalculate the Thevenin voltage and  resistance in this case, assuming all  sources are ideal.

[image: Ckt]

I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Use mesh analysis ( loop currents) or nodal analysis to find R1 and R2 and proceed in usual fashion.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler, I don't think that's the desired approach here.  It will work, of course, but there is a far simpler method that Olin and I have in mind and, further, is the most likely object of this exercise.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri . I think you mean we already assume a Thevenin circuit and a voltage source in place of Load resistance ; then solve 2 equations for two unknowns . Right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a black box that you are told is a Thevenin source.  You take two different pairs of current,voltage measurments.  How would you solve that?

Do you need to know if the inside is made of several sources with a mesh of resistors, or single voltage source with series resistance?  How would you tell the difference between these two cases?

Hint: much of the details of this problem are a distraction to see if you fall for getting lost in the minutia instead of thinking about the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this as an algebra problem in disguise. Remember making equations to describe lines on a graph? You've been given two points on a voltage vs. current graph for a *linear* circuit...